# PHP compiles incorrectly *with* zts support

Tags: php

I try to compile php 5.6, php 7.1 and php 7.3

To my surprise all them were compiled with ZTS.

I used same options I always use but this time something is different. I suspect is Apache but is also was compiled with my usual options.

Any idea?

## apache

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/httpd-2.4.41 --enable-modules=all --enable-mods-shared=all --enable-mpms-shared=all
```

## php

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/php-7.1.33-2.4 --with-apxs2=/usr/local/httpd-2.4.41/bin/apxs  \
--with-mysqli=shared --with-pdo-mysql=shared                                           \
--with-sqlite3=shared --with-pdo-sqlite=shared                                         \
--with-gd --with-jpeg-dir=/usr --with-png-dir=/usr --with-freetype-dir=/usr            \
--with-openssl=shared                                                                  \
--enable-pcntl=shared --enable-sockets=shared                                          \
--enable-ftp=shared                                                                    \
--with-curl=shared                                                                     \
--with-mhash=shared                                                                    \
--enable-wddx=shared                                                                   \
--enable-mbstring=shared                                                               \
--enable-intl=shared                                                                   \
--enable-exif=shared                                                                   \
--with-gmp=shared                                                                      \
--enable-calendar=shared                                                               \
--enable-soap=shared                                                                   \
--with-zlib=shared --enable-zip=shared                                                 \
--enable-bcmath=shared
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out like this:

Apache server might work with several MPM modules. May be 99% of PHP installations uses `MPM prefork`:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/prefork.html

In this mode, apache spawn several child processes via `fork()` and PHP does not need to be thread safe.

Under Linux this mode is very fast, since Linux have very fast `fork()`. It is as fast as thread based programs.

However, when Apache is installed the configuration file uses `MPM Worker`.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/worker.html

Instead of `fork()`, this mode uses threads. For this mode, PHP must be thread safe.

On Linux `MPM Worker` + PHP is slower than `MPM prefork`, but on other systems such Windows and MacOS, it is probably faster.

`MPM Worker` mode is selected by default in Apache configuration.

Since I just made `make install` and never changed Apache conf file selection was `MPM Worker`. This was pickup from PHP configure script and result was thread safe PHP.

I did select `MPM prefork` in Apache conf and PHP compilation was as expected.

Comment: Can you explain the solution in greater detail?